# Matching byte[] in C# and ROWVERSION type

Tags: c#, sql-server, byte

I have a problem fixing an issue we have left by the previous developer as I don't know what what the intent behind the code.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reports](
[ReportsId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](50) NULL
[Concurrency] [timestamp] NULL)
```

In our saveReport SP we have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SaveReport]
@ReportId INT,
@Description nvarchar(50),
@Concurrency ROWVERSION = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    --check if report and concurrency matches else throw error
    DECLARE @concur ROWVERSION = (SELECT Concurrency FROM Reports
                                        WHERE ReportId  = @ReportId)
    IF (@concur != @Concurrency)
    BEGIN
        --throw error
    END

--INSERT if new report/ update if reportid exist SCRIPT
END
```

I am currently fixing a bug wherein it is not updating the description

I tried copy pasting the payload from UI to swagger

It keeps on hitting the concurrency logic

```
IF (@concur != @Concurrency)
    BEGIN
        --throw error
    END
```

The concurrency on the payload doesn't seem to match the concurrency on the database. I am not even sure what it is for.

This is the type of data save on the database

```
0x00000000000009CD
0x00000000000009C9
.
.
.
```

While this is the type of data on the Request Payload I tried pasting on swagger

```
{concurrency: "AAAAAABo4Ao=",…}
```

This is the property on the dto

```
public byte[] Concurrency { get; set; }
```

May question would be:

1. What concurrency value do I pass on the payload to match the concurrency on the database table? Specifically `0x000000000068E034`

Comment: Your code needs to retrieve the existing value in order to pass it to the procedure. Does it? Perhaps the code serves no real purpose? Don't guess - go figure it out and remove it if that is the case. And note that a rowversion column in a table can never be NULL - defining it as such is very misleading and a logic error waiting to be encountered.

Comment: Normally you use `rowversion` (aka `timestamp`) to retrieve the transaction id of the last update, then when you make a new update you check it hasn't changed. It should be an 8-byte `byte[]` array